# JSON parsing in iOS with RestKit fails

Tags: ios, xml, json, mapping, restkit

I am building an iOS app, and I am using RestKit v0.20 for mapping a JSON file.
The JSON file structure is the next:

```
{
 "artists":{
  "@total":"100",
  "@page":"1",
  "@itemsPerPage":"30",
  "artist":[
   {
    "@sortName":"Ai Phoenix",
    "@name":"Ai Phoenix",
    "@mbid":"ffb0ac71-a438-4fce-91a5-58041aba0135",
    "url":"http:\/\/www.setlist.fm\/setlists\/ai-phoenix-13d78159.html"
   },
   {
    "@sortName":"Phoenix",
    "@name":"Phoenix",
    "@mbid":"02f4c1ff-65e0-4412-8e8b-6239b0faecb5",
    "url":"http:\/\/www.setlist.fm\/setlists\/phoenix-53d653f9.html"
   }
  ]
}
```

I don't know how to map these attributes that have the prefix "@" (@sortname, @name, @mbid). I have tried to map as a normal field (@"@name", @"@mbid", ...) and it fails. In the other hand, @"url" is working well for the "url" field. I have searched and all I have got is that this notation is because of a translation from a XML file, called [Badgerfish](http://badgerfish.ning.com/).

I this could help, have got the correspondant XML to this JSON file:

```
<artists total="100" page="1" itemsPerPage="30">
    <artist sortName="Ai Phoenix" name="Ai Phoenix" mbid="ffb0ac71-a438-4fce-91a5-    58041aba0135">
    <url>
        http://www.setlist.fm/setlists/ai-phoenix-13d78159.html
    </url>
</artist>
```

If anybody can help me, I would appreciate it. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known limitation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1204) of RestKit.

Quoting the framework's author himself:

> This is a known limitation and a consequence of RestKit's reliance on
>   Cocoa's key-value coding system for property access. The '@' prefix is
>   reserved for denominating key-value collection operators.
>
> You are going to need to change that JSON format to effectively work
>   with RestKit

Comment: Thanks Gabriele! I think I try to use XML alternative. Maybe I am wrong, but I have read that RestKit supports only json, I have to add a library to parse it. I have found in SO RKXMLReaderSerialization.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know RESTKit use KVC, and @ is used by KVC so can't use it in the JSON key names. Try to check if can change the @ prefix with something else, such as "m_".

Comment: Thank you Andrea! As I said to Gabriele, I will try XML file instead of JSON using RKXMLReaderSerialization.

Comment: I'm my opinion use XML is a sort of step back, I love JSON for its syntetic payload. If you feel confortable you can do your own "RestKit" and will not have problems. Or try to pre-elaborate the string removing the @ with another character

Comment: I will try to remove the @ character and map the file. Thanks Andrea!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using key paths for mapping another alternative might be to create a private RestKit branch and use objectForKey: and relatives instead of valueForKey:. In an iOS application you have to ship your own copy of RestKit anyway. (Did this for my simple app, and it works so far)

Comment: Thank you! I finally decided to use Apple's NSJSONSerialization, and it works perfect! I'll give RestKit a chance in the future.